# SQLite3 - convert human date to epoch

Tags: sqlite

I have dates in US format, and my database supports epoch (unixtime). Is it possible to convert using the SQLite3 query?

```
INSERT INTO candles_USD_BCH (id, timestamp) values (null, 2018-03-31 01:02:03);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO candles_USD_BCH (id, timestamp) 
  values (null, CAST(strftime('%s', '2018-03-31 01:02:03') as integer));
```

The CAST() is probably not essential in SQLite, but I think it's a good habit. The function `strftime()` returns a string.

[SQLite Date and Time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), and pay attention to the section "Caveats and Bugs".

Comment: `INSERT INTO candles_USD_BCH values (null, strftime('%s','2022-03-31 01:02:03'));`
is working. Thanks!